# Exportar de access a csv

Tags: vba, ms-access

Quiero exportar una tabla de access a csv (o txt)

Creo un módulo nuevo y pongo:

```
Public Function Exportar()

Dim micsv As String

micsv = "C:\prueba\prueba.csv"

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "TABLA", micsv, False

MsgBox "Exportación realizada correctamente", vbInformation, "Prueba"

End Function
Sub ejecu()

End Sub
```

Me sale

```
error 3441
El separador de campo de especificación de archivo de texto coincide con el separador decimal o el delimitador de texto.
```

No consigo arreglarlo.

Comment: Hola. Al parecer este problema ocurre debido a la confusión de ciertos delimitadores cuando tus programas de Microsoft están en un idioma distinto del inglés. Debes crear un archivo de especificación de importaciones e indicar que quieres usar dicho archivo en el segundo parámetro, algo así: `DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, "tuEspecificacionDeImportacion", "TABLA", micsv, False`. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59767493/5587982) y también [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26993110/5587982).

Comment: Revisa también lo que dice [la documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/access.docmd.transfertext#parameters) sobre el parámetro `SpecificationName` y sobre las distintas formas de crearlo y dónde debería ir ese archivo.

Comment: Primero verifica idioma/región de Windows, no es lo mismo *Español-España* que *Español-<Algún país Latinoamericano>*.

Comment: El problema es q es el ordenador del trabajo y no puedo tocar ninguna configuración. No tengo permiso para modificar nada.

Comment: En ese caso, debes pedir a un administrador que te cree el archivo de especificación que necesitas.